# allocate AWS ec2 private IP address and EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a private ip address that I would like to allocate to an EMR instance. I could assign a secondary ip address to the EMR master node. However, my EMR instance is only occasionally up. How can I prevent DHCP from allocating this private ip when the EMR instance is not available?

Answer (score 0):

See [How do I assign a static private IP address to the master node of my Amazon EMR cluster?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/static-private-ip-master-node-emr/)

More generally, when launching EC2 you can indicate a specific private IP and it will be assigned to the instance's primary network interface (assuming the IP is within the subnet's CIDR and is not already in use).

Also, a private IPv4 address remains associated with the network interface when the instance is stopped and restarted, so it shouldn't change over a stop/start.